# What is the source of 'Compile Error' message in a project built upon MNRAS template in overleaf?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, xetex, templates

I am trying to make a paper using **MNRAS** template in [Overleaf website](https://www.overleaf.com).
Once I added all my references to **.bib** file and added the file to my project, I noticed that there is a

> Compile Error

giving me the following message:

> ./mn2e.bbl:22: Runaway argument? \protect \citeauthoryear {{Betoule},
>   {Kessler}, {Guy}, {Mosher}, {Har\ETC. Paragraph ended before
>   \@lbibitem was complete.  \par l.22

Even though I am able to continue typing my write-up but the document is not being updated due to this error message. I would really appreciate your help in figuring out a working solution. I can also share my **.bib** file along with **latex log** file if you think that might help to find the solution.

Sincerely,

Below this line you can see a working example of **.tex** file followed by **.bib** file.
________________________________(**.tex**)___________________________________

```
\documentclass[useAMS,usenatbib]{mn2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\def\aap{Astronomy \& Astrophysics}
\def\apj{The Astrophysical Journal}
\def\mnras{Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society}

\title[]{Title}

\author[]{A. Lastname1$^{1}$\thanks{E-mail: Email1}, D. Lastname2$^{1}$\thanks{E-mail: Email2} and P. Lastname3$^{1}$\thanks{E-mail: Email3}\\
$^{1}$Department of Astronomy, Official Name of the University\\}

\begin{document}
\date{Accepted . Received ; in original form }
\pagerange{\pageref{firstpage}--\pageref{lastpage}} \pubyear{2016}
\maketitle
\label{firstpage}

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
supernovae:general, cosmology:observation
\end{keywords}

\section{Introduction}

\section{Methodology}

\section{Data Acquisition}

\section{Analaysis}

\section{Results}

\section{Discussion}

\section{Conclusions}

\begin{itemize}
\item{Item 1}
\item{Item 2}
\item{Item 3}
\end{itemize}

\section*{Acknowledgments}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{mn2e}
\bibliography{references}
\label{lastpage}
\end{document}
```

_______________________________(**.bib**)____________________________________

```
@Article{2014A&A...568A..22B,
  author =        {{Betoule}, M. and {Kessler}, R. and {Guy}, J. and {Mosher}, J. and {Hardin}, D. and {Biswas}, R. and {Astier}, P. and {El-Hage}, P. and {Konig}, M. and {Kuhlmann}, S. and {Marriner}, J. and {Pain}, R. and {Regnault}, N. and {Balland}, C. and {Bassett}, B.~A. and {Brown}, P.~J. and {Campbell}, H. and {Carlberg}, R.~G. and {Cellier-Holzem}, F. and {Cinabro}, D. and {Conley}, A. and {D'Andrea}, C.~B. and {DePoy}, D.~L. and {Doi}, M. and {Ellis}, R.~S. and {Fabbro}, S. and {Filippenko}, A.~V. and {Foley}, R.~J. and {Frieman}, J.~A. and {Fouchez}, D. and {Galbany}, L. and {Goobar}, A. and {Gupta}, R.~R. and {Hill}, G.~J. and {Hlozek}, R. and {Hogan}, C.~J. and {Hook}, I.~M. and {Howell}, D.~A. and {Jha}, S.~W. and {Le Guillou}, L. and {Leloudas}, G. and {Lidman}, C. and {Marshall}, J.~L. and {M{\"o}ller}, A. and {Mour{\~a}o}, A.~M. and {Neveu}, J. and {Nichol}, R. and {Olmstead}, M.~D. and {Palanque-Delabrouille}, N. and {Perlmutter}, S. and {Prieto}, J.~L. and {Pritchet}, C.~J. and {Richmond}, M. and {Riess}, A.~G. and {Ruhlmann-Kleider}, V. and {Sako}, M. and {Schahmaneche}, K. and {Schneider}, D.~P. and {Smith}, M. and {Sollerman}, J. and {Sullivan}, M. and {Walton}, N.~A. and {Wheeler}, C.~J.},
  title =         {{Improved cosmological constraints from a joint analysis of the SDSS-II and SNLS supernova samples}},
  journal =       {\aap},
  year =          {2014},
  volume =        {568},
  pages =         {A22},
  month =         aug,
  adsnote =       {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System},
  adsurl =        {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2014A%26A...568A..22B},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  doi =           {10.1051/0004-6361/201423413},
  eid =           {A22},
  eprint =        {1401.4064},
  keywords =      {cosmology: observations, distance scale, dark energy}
}
```

Comment: a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) woul be more helpful in finding a fast solution.

Comment: The `mn2e.bst` style file has a hard-coded limit of 250 characters in the string passed as optional argument to `\bibitem`, so your `.bbl` file ends up to be malformed. If I try with `plainnat.bst`, there is no problem.

Comment: I think the  problem is with the bst and the long list on authors. The `bst` is supposed to create a `\bibitem` with the following format `\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{long author}{short author}{year}]{label}`. For some reasons the `bst` stops parsing in the middle of the list of authors for `long author`

Comment: @egreg if you use `plainnat` the string is longer that 250 character, but it is generated.

Comment: @Guido As I said in my comment.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Is this suggesting that if I try to remove some authors names manually, at some point I will hit the minimum allowed string length and then the compiler won't complain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When BibTeX is run, there are two warnings

```
Warning--you've exceeded 250, the entry-string-size, for entry 2014A&A...568A..22B
while executing--line 1183 of file mn2e.bst
*Please notify the bibstyle designer*
Warning--you've exceeded 250, the entry-string-size, for entry 2014A&A...568A..22B
while executing--line 1222 of file mn2e.bst
*Please notify the bibstyle designer*
```

The problem is that the `mn2e.bst` style file uses the internal variable `entry.max$` that's initialized at runtime according to a value in `texmf.cnf`

```
776 % BibTeX only (max_strings also determines hash_size and hash_prime).
777 ent_str_size =  250
778 glob_str_size = 20000
779 max_strings.bibtex = 35307
```

(line numbers added for convenience).

Indeed, if I call `bibtex` from the command line with

```
ent_str_size=2000 bibtex benjamin
```

I can get the `.bbl` correctly produced, because the assignment overrides the default value.

Other `natbib` compatible styles don't use the value of `entry.max$`, so they have no problem.

How to change the situation with Overleaf I don't know; the problematic bit seems to be in the functions `presort` and `bib.sort.order`
they seems to be common in APA based bib styles. The standard `plainnat.bst` file has no mention of `entry.max$` in the `bib.sort.order` function and indeed it produces a working `.bbl` file.

---

On the other hand, if I use the `mnras` class and the `mnras.bst` style file, I get no error; the entry is typeset as

[image]

Note that `mn2e.cls` and `mn2e.bst` are not distributed any more in TeX Live (they are in the `doc` tree in a `legacy` subdirectory), which seems to imply that the Royal Astronomic Society considers them as obsolete.